# suspend embedded python script execution

Tags: python, embed

I have an app that embeds python scripting.

I'm adding calls to python from C, and my problem is that i need to suspend the script execution let the app run, and restore the execution from where it was suspended.

The idea is that python would call, say "WaitForData" function, so at that point the script must suspend (pause) the calls bail out so the app event loop would continue. When the necessary data is present, i would like to restore the execution of the script, it is like the python call returns at that point.

i'm running single threaded python.

any ideas how can i do this, or something similar, where i'll have the app event loop run before python call exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only way I could come up with is to run the Python engine on a separate thread. Then the main thread is blocked when the python thread is running.

When I need to suspend, I block the Python thread, and let the main thread run. When necessary, the OnIdle of the main thread, i block it and let the python continue.

it seems to be working fine.